# Stopping touch gesture of an active pane penetrating and activating object behind it in Visual Studio 2019 adn dotnetbrowser

Tags: visual-studio-2019, webbrowser-control, touch-event, touchscreen, dotnetbrowser

First of all, I am a project manager in developing a browser for a specific use at client's corporation.  My experience is in network infrastructure however I know a tiny bit programming and what it can do due to extra study for this project.  It is developed with Teamdev's dotnetbrowser for browsing in Visual Studio 2019 for the rest of the requirement and must run in touch screen.

Here is what beats us, hopefully someone else might run into this issue and can offer a little way out. Our browser is based on (according to our overseas programmer) multiple panes.  There are at least 5 panes with 2 is hidden and showing up based on touch/click event.  One of the hidden and showing pane based on a touch event is navigational menu pane. The issue with menu pane is that everytime the icon in the menu pane that was located in front of the main pane is touched, it also activates the object behind it.  As an example, if the main pane is currently showing a website then the menu pane which consists only Back, Forward and Home icons is pressed, it also create either an impression in the website at the back being pressed or sometimes it activates the link in the area as if the link at the back pane is at the front/in focus and clicked.  Also, the main requirement of this project is to use the entire touch screen area for browsing therefore the menu has to be hidden and showing pretty much leave us a little room to develop anything else taking the some screen space.

Would anyone have an idea to stop it from happening so the click at the front pane does not penetrate or activate whatever object or link behind it.  We have not tried any tricks yet because we went through MS docs but couldn't see it possible to alter the circumstances.

I look forward to your suggestions.

Regards,

risardi